# Spring XD stream status failed

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-xd, gemfire

After creating stream in Spring XD using the below command

***stream create foo --definition "jdbc --fixedDelay=1 --split=1 --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --query='select * from test_tutorials_tbl'|log" --deploy***

we have got the status as 'Created and deployed new stream 'foo'.

But when I checked with the stream list command, the status seems to be failed and no data. This is not with the case with MySql database alone but with a command like

***'stream create --name stocks --definition "http --port=9090 | gemfire-json-server --regionName=Customers --keyExpression=payload.getField('lastname')" --deploy'***

is too failing.

Could any one please help us as this work is very much critical.

Comment: Hi,

What do you see at the XD container log when these modules are getting deployed and subsequently failed?

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this. Can you please direct me where i can find these logs? i checked in xd/logs folder in spring-xd but the folder is empty.

Comment: This is dependent on your own Spring XD configuration.  I would talk to the guy who is administrating your Spring XD containers, or check the [Spring XD manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/) for default logging locations if you're the one administrating the containers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the question that i have posted. Try starting the Spring XD single node too. Then you won't face any stream creation failure. Status will be in deployed (when we try create stream to fetch mysql data for example). But stream creation will be in failed, if we are pointing to gemfire. I am looking into it.